# Are there examples of finite-dimensional complex non-semisimple non-commutative symmetric Frobenius algebras?

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, topological-quantum-field-theory, frobenius-algebras

Are there any examples of finite-dimensional complex non-semisimple non-commutative symmetric Frobenius algebras? Or can one show that none exist?

I went through [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.0932.pdf) list of all complex associative algebras up to dimension $4$ and couldn't find any non-commutative non-semisimple ones that can be equipped with a corresponding linear form to make them into a symmetric Frobenius algebra. Are there examples in higher dimensions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given any finite dimensional algebra $A$, consider the linear dual $\hat{A}= \hom(A, k)$ as an $A$-$A$-bimodule. Then $R = A \oplus \hat{A}$ may be equipped with an algebra structure as follows:

$$(a, x) \cdot (b,y) = (ab, x \cdot b + a \cdot y)$$

for $a,b \in A$ and $x,y \in \hat{A}$. The algebra $R$ has a natural symmetric Frobenius algebra structure. So every finite dimensional (possibly non-commutative) algebra embeds into a symmetric Frobenius algebra.

Comment: Is it obvious that there are (non-commutative) examples for which the resulting symmetric Frobenius algebra is non-semisimple?

Comment: @AndiBauer yes it is, since $\hat{A}$ is then a 2-sided ideal with zero law. So the resulting $R=R_A$ is not semisimple unless $A=0$ (and not commutative as soon as $A$ is not).

Comment: Wow... how does one see $R$ is self-injective? What's the associated form?

Comment: The bilinear form is $\langle (a,f), (b,g) \rangle = f(b) + g(a)$.

Comment: @YCor, so if I take one of the two non-commutative (non-unital, non-semisimple) 2-dimensional associative algebras as $A$, the resulting 4-dimensional $R$ would be non-commutative and non-semisimple? This would mean I overlooked something when I went through the list of associative algebras linked in the question...

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries, sorry, can you say more about what the product in the second component $x\cdot b+a\cdot y$ is, i.e. how $\hat{A}$ is a bimodule? I first thought this is just the left- and right action of $A$ onto itself after identifying the vector space with its dual. But then, $R$ would be just the tensor product of $A$ with the 2-dimensional non-unital commutative algebra.

Comment: @AndiBauer The standard actions of $A,A$ on $Hom(M,k)$ would be $(r\cdot f)(m)=f(mr)$ and $(f\cdot r)(m)=f(rm)$, which is my estimate at what is intended.

Comment: Is there somewhere where this construction is discussed more generally in print? Perhaps even in the non-finite dimensional case? (It seems like the bilinear form still has meaning in the non f.d. case)

Comment: @AndiBauer The action that rschwieb writes is correct. We use the usual action on $\hat{A}$.

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries Does $A$ not need to be unital for this to work? Otherwise, what's the linear form $\mu$ that generates the Frobenius form through the product? If there is a unit $1$, one could take $\mu=(0,1)$.

Comment: @AndiBauer You said "algebras". I assumed you meant unital or would have said otherwise. Of course unital algebras are also not-necessarily unital algebras, so this still gives examples asked for in the OP.  If A is unital, then the bilinear form is induced by the counit $\epsilon(a,f) = f(1)$. If $A$ is non-unital, then I guess there is no counit, but the bilinear form still makes sense and is symmetric and non-degenerate.

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries Thanks, that explains my confusion about there being non-commutative non-semisimple 2-dimensional algebras but no non-commutative non-semisimple 4-dimensional symmetric Frobenius algebras -- the former are not unital.

Answer (score 0):

I just realize that my question is actually rather trivial the way I posed it: There exist non-commutative semisimple examples (with the $2\times 2$ matrix algebra being the smallest example). There also exist commutative non-semisimple examples, the smallest one given by
$$e_0\cdot e_0 = e_0,\quad e_0\cdot e_1=e_1,\\
e_1\cdot e_0=e_1,\quad \mu(e_1)=1\;,$$
where $\mu$ is the linear form generating the symmetric non-degenerate pairing and all other entries $0$.

All one needs to do is consider direct sums or tensor products of a non-commutative (but semisimple) and a non-semisimple (but commutative) example, and it will be both non-commutative and non-semisimple. The smallest such example is of dimension $6$.

I guess a more sensible but a bit artificial question to ask would have been whether there are examples that do not come from the tensor product or direct sum of a commutative and a semi-simple example.